# How to resize DatePicker android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

How do I re size the datepicker widget in android (the default one)

Comment: Yes we can't do that as
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302092/resizing-of-datepicker-in-android/7631695#7631695

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is not possible to resize the DatePicker-widget.