# Resizing of DatePicker in android

Tags: android, datepicker

How can I reduce the size (height and width) of a DatePicker? Is there any built-in method available for this?

Comment: Follow this answer, It will work.http://stackoverflow.com/a/34523787/1983018

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You cannot reduce the size of a view beyond their minimum size. 
Using wrap_content ensures that the DatePicker is just big enough to enclose its contents.

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: please suggest me there is no way for doing it or by using custom layout .

Answer (score 13):

Example of a DatePicker that is half it's original size.

```
<DatePicker
   android:id="@+id/datePicker"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:calendarViewShown="false"
   android:scaleX=".5"
   android:scaleY=".5" />
```

Comment: this shrinks the picker within its rectangle, but does not resize the view's rectangle.  that markup shows a half-size picker, but it appears in a rectangle computed at full size.  this means you cannot place elements "next" to it without overriding padding and margins of those elements.

Comment: `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'scaleX' in package 
 'android'`

Answer (score 10):

to reduce the space occupied by the datepicker, I used both options:

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

will look like this, which is pretty much standard and also used by a number of other apps, and does not take too much space

[image: DatePicker in Spinner mode with no calendar shown]

Comment: unless you're making a fancy calendar app or something, this is enough for selecting a date. thanks op

Answer (score 2):

N, we can't reduce the size of the date picker in Android, but for setting a date in our program we can use the Date Picker Dialog box. Here is the link related to that:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Answer (score 2):

I think we can not reduce the actual size of the date picker view but we can use scaling and negative padding properties to make the date picker look smaller.

Scaling down the date picker by using android:scaleY and android:scaleX attributes will make the picker to look smaller but still take the same amount of view space inside the activity/ fragment. To remove the extra space around the scaled down version of date picker we can use negative padding.

For example, if we want to place two scaled down version of date pickers side by side without leaving much gap between them, then we can do so by adjusting the padding as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
     <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:padding="-40dp"
        android:scaleY="0.80"
        android:scaleX="0.80"/>

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:padding="-40dp"
        android:scaleY="0.80"
        android:scaleX="0.80"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Above example shows placing the 2 date pickers side by side but we can place any other view beside a date picker by adjusting the padding as shown above.

Comment: @HaydenKai yes, padding is not working,  let use margin