# Can i resize the DateTimePicker used in android?

Tags: android, resize, widget

Can i resize the DateTimePcker widget in the android UI?

In my application xml I have to place multiple controls in the same screen, hence I need to resize the datetimepicker.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible. Your question is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302092/resizing-of-datepicker-in-android)

I remember doing my own implementation of this, or actually the NumberPicker which is what the DatePicker is using, which was fairly straight forward. Unfortunately my code is not reusable as is.